# Magento 2.3 - If two specific products on cart show free shipping for both and if one of these two products is on cart show shipping price

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I'm using the cart pricing rule in magento 2, I have created the attribute "is free shipping?"= yes for only 5 Gallons variation.
[image]

Free shipping is only applied if 5 gallons variation is on cart, Which is working fine.

[image]

I want to add free shipping to one of it's cross-sell products too if specific cross-sell product is also in cart with 5 gallons variation.

[image]

Here is my cart price rule:
[image]

Please anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `is Free Shipping is not one of No`

Instead of `is` use `is not one of`.

I hope this work for you

Comment: Gohil Rajesh It's only showing these three options ( is, is not, is undefined )

Comment: "undefined " ?? .. that mean something wrong on your site. fix it first